# Bash: Why does my If-Statement always evaluate to true?

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement

I'm trying to write what would seem to be a simple if statement in most languages, however in bash this doesnt seem to work at all.

When I run the script it always enters the first if statement. Can anyone offer help me as to what I am doing wrong?

```
PERC=.5
    if [  "$PERC" > "1.00" ]
            then
                    echo "Entered first statement"
            else
                    if [ "$PERC" < "1.00" ]
                            then
                                    echo "Entered second statement"
                    fi
    fi
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Where did you read that `>` and `<` are valid arguments to `[`?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I didn't, It's used in java, c++,c,Haskell, and most other languages i have used. I have saw people use it and not use it in bash, I have also saw people use -lt and -gt but that also never worked for me.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: `help test` mentions `<` and `>` as string operators, so why shouldn't they be valid arguments, even if unsuitable for comparing numbers (and with redirection in mind)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`>` and `<` compare strings, not numbers (and must be backslashed or quoted in single `[...]`). Use `-gt`, `-lt` etc. to compare numbers, or use arithmetic conditions:

```
if (( a < b || b <= c )) ; then
```

Note, however, that bash only handles integer arithmetics. To compare floats, you can use `bc`:

```
if [[ 1 == $( bc <<< '1.5 < 1.00' ) ]] ; then
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I just copied your bottom example exactly and i get an error saying :
syntax error near `)'
line 7: `if [[ 1== $( bc <<< '1.5 < 1.00' ) ]]'
any ideas?

Comment: @EthanMcTiernan: A space is missing before `==` in your exact copy.

Answer (score 2):

`>` and `<` are the I/O redirection operators. So

```
if [ "$PERC" > "1.0" ]
```

is executing the command `[ "$PERC ]`, redirecting the output to the file `1.0`, and then `if` is testing whether the command succeeded. `[ "$PERC" ]` simply tests whether `"$PERC"` is a non-empty string.

To use them as operators in the `test` command, you need to quote or escape them:

```
if [ "$PERC" '>' "1.0" ]
```

You could also use bash's `[[` conditional syntax instead of the `[` command:

```
if [[ $PERC > "1.0" ]]
```